# SQL and C# Error: Error on SQL procedure: Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am working on a SQL Server database program which has 2 `dateTimePickers` on its interface to choose DOJ (Date Of Join) and DOB (Date of Birth). Everything seems to be working well except the `dateTimePickers`, it keeps coming up with:

> Error converting nvarchar to datetime

I have tried changing it to `nvarchar(50)` and `nvarchar(MAX)` but then it comes up with a different error along the same lines. The form looks like this, with also said error coming up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/edBbl.png

This is the SQL Server stored procedure:

```sql
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StudentAdd]
    @FirstName varchar(50),
    @LastName varchar(50),
    @CourseEnrolled varchar(250),
    @Level int,
    @DOJ datetime,
    @DOB datetime
AS
    INSERT INTO tblStudent (First_Name, Last_Name, Course_Enrolled, Level, DOJ, DOB) 
    VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @CourseEnrolled, @Level, @DOJ, @DOB)
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace final_assessment
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-SQ1V840;Initial Catalog=UserRegistration;Integrated Security=True";

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("StudentAdd", sqlCon))
                    {
                        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", textBox1.Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", textBox2.Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseEnrolled", textBox3.Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Level", textBox4.Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOJ", dateTimePicker1.Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", dateTimePicker2.Text.Trim());

                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Registration successful");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Error in the SQL Server \"StudentAdd\" procedure: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Likely it's not the length of the text that's the problem but the format of the datetimepicker's DateTime getting formatted to string differently than SQL Server expects. Use an SqlParameter with `SqlDbType.DateTime` and the actual `DateTime` value from the datetimepicker control. See also [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: so where do i put the code to be exact? I am quite confused on these two comments because they dont give me a proper real answer on what to do here

Comment: Does `dateTimePicker1` have a `Value` property? If so, what is its **Type**?

Comment: I _suspect_ you want to use `dateTimePicker1.Value` rather than `dateTimePicker1.Text.Trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code in CSharp.

```cs
using (SqlConnection openCon = new SqlConnection("Server=YourServerName;Database=YourDBName;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
{
    string saveStaff = "INSERT into test (a) VALUES (@dateValue)";

    using (SqlCommand querySaveStaff = new SqlCommand(saveStaff))
    {
        querySaveStaff.Connection = openCon;
         querySaveStaff.Parameters.Add("@dateValue", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;

        openCon.Open();

        querySaveStaff.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: And for best practice, the strings should be `sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = textBox1.Text.Trim();` with the datatype and precision matching the SP definition.

Comment: The string doesnt work with my dateTimePicker for some reason.. Also Do I put the code that you put for the querySaveStuff to the button click or?

Comment: @DaleK Honestly, I am not sure why this is controversial or confusing. If you want to pass an `int` - pass an `int`. If you want to pass a `nvarchar` - pass a `string`. If you want to pass a `datetime` - pass a `DateTime`. :)

Comment: @mjwills thanks for that - I just ran a test, because I had assumed that `new SqlParameter("@Test", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = "29 mar 2020" };` would carry out the conversion as `Value` is assigned, but I can see that is not the case, despite declaring the parameter as a DateType, its still a string that is passed to the database. Thats not the behaviour I expected TBH. Thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score -1):

I saw you are passing values to your procedure without mentioning their types, it is better to show each parameter type to be far away from many other problems in the future.

At first check if your SQL Table column type is set to DATETIME. If it so you need to check your C# string format. SQL use "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff" date format. If you pass your string with this value: "2020-04-06 9:24:15.144" it will pass without any errors. But you have to show ADO.NET that you are passing a DATETIME.

If you don't want to deal with string you have to parse it to `DateTime` with your format of string and then pass it to your procedure.

Example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("YOUR DATE STRING", "YOUR DATET STRING FORMAT", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

But if you don't want to parse string to `DateTime` use this (this will work for string and datetime types).

Here is example:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string csharpDate = "2020-06-04 09:37:15.144";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("YOUR PROCEDURE NAME", connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@DateParameter", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = csharpDate;
            await connection.OpenAsync();
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass dates, not strings. **Do not use this answer.**